# How to include UIkit from Bower Asset inside Yii2 AppAsset

Tags: php, yii2, bower

I have installed a package that enables me add and make use of uikit css and js files. 
It enables me to add the css files and js files by adding the following code to `main.php`.

`\worstinme\uikit\Asset::register($this);`

This code adds the css to the header and the js file to the footer. However, I am not able to control their positions so it conflicts with some other files I added. 
See below:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/fonts/style.min.css',
        'css/fonts/s9dicons.css',
        'css/template.css', 
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/main.js',   
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset', \\ loads jquery
        //'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

In my main layout head, I have the codes below:

```
\worstinme\uikit\Asset::register($this);
AppAsset::register($this);
```

If I use the above, it loads `uikit.css` **first** **before** style.min.css, s9dicons.css and template.css which is fine BUT in the footer, it also loads `uikit.js` **first** before `jquery.js` and `main.js` which is wrong. If I placed `\worstinme\uikit\Asset::register($this);` after `AppAsset::register($this);`, the problem will be the other way around.

How can I place this in a way that the `uikit.css` file loads first and the `uikit.js` file load after `jquery.js` **but not before** `main.js`?

The `worstinme` application fetches the uikit css and js files from `vendor/bower-assets/uikit`. I checked its `Asset.php` file and found the code below:

```
namespace worstinme\uikit;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class Asset extends AssetBundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/uikit/dist';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $css = [
        'css/uikit.min.css',
    ];

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $js = [
        'js/uikit.min.js',
    ];

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $depends = [

    ];

}
```

So I am thinking, can I avoid using `\worstinme\uikit\Asset::register($this);` and just get the `uikit.css` and `uikit.js` separately from the source into the `AppAsset.php` directly as the solution? Seems like I will be able to control their position when separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a file `UikitAsset.php` inside the assets folder.
It contains the code below:

```
<?php

namespace app\assets; 

use yii\web\AssetBundle; 

class UikitAsset extends AssetBundle 
{ 
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/uikit/dist'; 
    public $baseUrl = '@web'; 
    public $css = [
        'css/uikit.min.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/uikit.min.js',
    ];
}
```

I then proceed to `AppAsset.php` and added the code as below:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main frontend application asset bundle.
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/fonts/style.min.css',
        'css/fonts/s9dicons.css',
        'css/template.css', 
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/main.js',   
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        '\app\assets\UikitAsset',
    ];
}
```

That fixed the issue. Placing the css file and the js file in their right places. I also did not have to add `\worstinme\uikit\Asset::register($this);`to my layout file head again to load the files.